# IPhone 6 Plus and 7 locking up

Tags: iphone

I had a locking up problem on my 6 Plus and after talking to a Apple Tech higher up the food chain he said it was a software bug somewhere and that I would need to reset and start over as a new phone. Instead I bought a 7 and started over with my 6 as a backup. The 7 worked fine until I turned off the Icloud Contacts at which time the problem is now on teh 7 too. I even reset it as a new phone and teh problem continues. What can I do?

Comment: Reset the device and start it over as a new phone. The tech wasn't kidding about that.

Comment: Unfortunately I've done that three times to no avail. I'm working on some ideas

Answer (score -1):

you could try downgrading to an older version of ios. you would need to put the device into what is called DFU mode or recovery mode, see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15qaTA4lQPc

you will also need to download the version of ios you want from here 
https://ipsw.me/

once downloaded, put your device into dfu mode, open itunes, hold shift and click restore, browse to where you downloaded the firmware file and install it

Comment: iPhone 7 cannot run versions of iOS prior to 10. iPhone 6 can, but you cannot downgrade iOS unless Apple is still signing installations of the previous version. The site you linked indicates only 9.3.5 is currently being signed, and I wouldn't hold my breath on that lasting much longer. (Typically it's about a month after the new release, and we're already past that date.)

Comment: Also as of today (October 18th, 2016), Apple had stopped signing iOS 9.3.5 (https://twitter.com/TSSstatus/status/788521816880840705)

Comment: oh, fair enough, would have been worth a try if they were still signing